# Порядок выбора полей в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Стало интересно. Например есть таблица и в ней 2 поля: id и uid

Я допустим делаю выборку и перечисляю поля в разном порядке:

SELECT `uid`, `id`

Это может например как-то замедлять запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/141767/) про кластерные и некластерные индексы. никакого отношения к порядку полей в select они не имеют. только к выражениям в `on`, `where` и `order by`. т.е. только в тех местах где идет сравнение значений полей - фильтрация или сортировка. кластерный индекс имеет преимущество перед "обычным" в скорости, но опять же речь **не** о выражении в select.
на скорость может влиять только порядок полей в индексе (если он составной), ну и при условии если этот индекс, конечно, используется. и тут неважно какой это индекс (кластерный или нет).

Answer (score 0):

В SELECT - сомнительно, но кто вам мешает сделать тест самостоятельно?

B WHERE - замечал довольно таки большую разницу, для увеличения быстродействия первыми задавал параметры, которые "отсеивают" больше записей, так же обращая внимание на тип поля (enum, tinyint в начале условия достаточно ускоряли время выполнения запросов)

Answer (score -2):

Повлияет только в случае использования кластерного индекса.

Если есть кластерный индекс id, uid, то запрос SELECT id, uid, будет покрывающим(т.е. в самом индексе будет данных достаточно для формирования ответа). А т.к. mysql пытается индексы хранить в памяти, то соответственно не будет обращений к hd.  В mysql, чтобы индекс стал покрывающим в select необходимо указывать поля в том же порядке, в каком они расположены в индексе.
А для запроса SELECT uid, id индекс уже не будет покрывающим, соответственно будет обращение к hd.

Comment: @exeption, кластерный индекс это составной или что? Как это понять?

Comment: бред. отличие explain extended в студию.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, а Вы что скажете? Не повлияет?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, превратите комментарий в ответ. Вы как всегда даете четкие ответы и пояснения :)

Comment: @ModaL преобразовал